# How to add an itemprop to span tag with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, microformats

I want to add an itemprop to a span tag with jQuery.

My corrent code is:

```
<div class="top-telephone"><span>+00 00 00 00 00</span></div>
```

I want my code to look like:

```
<div class="top-telephone"><span itemprop="telephone">+00 00 00 00 00</span></div>
```

I tried using `jQuery('span[itemprop="telephone"]').append(jQuery('.top-telephone'));` but that did not work for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('span[itemprop="telephone"]').append(jQuery('.top-telephone'));
```

In your code you use `Attribute Equals Selector`. which use to select element with specified attribute.

**Attribute Equals Selector :** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.

By this code `jQuery('span[itemprop="telephone"]')` , you can select element which have attribute `itemprop` with `telephone` value.

[Read about attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

But in you case, you want to append a attribute to a element. For this you can use jquery `.attr()` or `.prop()`.

Try this:-

```
jQuery('.top-telephone span').prop('itemprop', 'telephone');

$('.top-telephone span').prop('itemprop','telephone');
```

OR

```
jQuery('.top-telephone span').attr('itemprop', 'telephone');

$('.top-telephone span').attr('itemprop','telephone');
```

OR

```
jQuery('.top-telephone').find('span').attr('itemprop', 'telephone');

$('.top-telephone').find('span').attr('itemprop','telephone');
```

[Jquery .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

[Jquery .prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: Awesome, this works fine :)

`jQuery('.top-telephone span').attr('itemprop', 'telephone');`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off, as you can't select the element by the `itemprop` attibute because it doesn't yet exist. Try this:

```
jQuery('.top-telephone span').prop('itemprop', 'telephone');
```

If you are using an old version of jQuery (< 1.6), you will need to use `attr()` instead of `prop()`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$('.top-telephone').children('span').prop('itemprop','telephone');
```

or

```
$('.top-telephone').children('span').attr('itemprop','telephone');
```